# Geld, das man vor der Frau versteckt

Tags: single-word-request

Im Polnischen existiert das Wort **zaskórniaki**, welches Geld bezeichnet, das man(n) vor seiner Frau und Familie versteckt, um sich dafür etwas zu gönnen.

Als deutsche Übersetzung habe ich **Biergeld** und **Notgroschen** gefunden. Inwieweit weisen diese Wörter auf eine ähnliche Bedeutung hin? Wie klingen diese Sätze im Deutschen?

> Ich glaube, mein Mann hat irgendwo Biergeld heimlich einstecken.
>
> Die meisten verheirateten Männer haben irgendwo ihre Notgroschen.

Gibt es vielleicht einen besseren Begriff?

Comment: Es gibt noch "stille Reserven" (http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/polnisch-deutsch/zask%C3%B3rniaki)

Comment: Das habe ich auch gesehen, erschien mir von den dreien aber am wenigsten passend.

Comment: Ich finde es passender als Notgroschen, aber ich versteh auch kein polnisch. Notgroschen würde ich aus einem Bauchgefühl ausschließen. Das ist tatsächlich für einen Notfall reserviert.

Comment: Klar, deswegen frage ich hier im Forum weil ich auch selbst nicht besser weiß :) Kann ja sein, dass du Recht hast :) Das Wort ist umgangssprachlich und impliziert die Geheimniskrämerei um die paar zurückgelegten Scheine.

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht, jemals ein Wort für sowas gehört zu haben. Ein Notgroschen ist ja etwas, was man für den Notfall oder schlechte Zeiten zurücklegt, passt daher nicht so gut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aus meiner Familie kenne ich "Schmugeld". Das ist das, was z. B. am Ende des Monats vom Haushaltsgeld übrig ist und vor dem Partner verheimlicht wird. Wenn du mal danach googlest, findest du es auch in verschiedenen Wörterbüchern.

Comment: Hah! http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmugeld Volltreffer! Danke!

Comment: Ihr habt am Ende des Monats Haushaltsgeld übrig? o_o

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar offiziell, natürlich nicht ^^

Comment: Hab ich noch nie gehört, aber passt perfekt. +1

Comment: Noch nie gehört, müsste im Durchschnitt vermutlich erläutert werden. Nichtsdestotrotz +1

Comment: Sehe ich auch so, aber meine Mutter hat es verwendet. Ich war überrascht, dass es dann doch in mehreren Wörterbüchern geführt wird. Der Duden schreibt aber auch "landschaftlich".